# cannot resolve method sort using a comparator from apache common io

Tags: java, apache, file, sorting, comparator

I'm using apache Commons IO to compare and sort an array of `File[]` type.

```
import org.apache.commons.io.comparator.*;
public abstract class Order {

static final String ABS = "abs", TYPE = "type", SIZE = "size";


    public static void runOrder(File[] filteredFiles, String[] command) {
    String currentOrder = command[0];
    File[] sortedFiles = null;
    if (command.length == 1) { //according to original order
        if (currentOrder.equals(ABS))
            sortedFiles = NameFileComparator.NAME_COMPARATOR.sort(filteredFiles);
        if (currentOrder.equals(TYPE))
            sortedFiles = ExtensionFileComparator.EXTENSION_COMPARATOR.sort(filteredFiles);
        if (currentOrder.equals(SIZE))
            sortedFiles = SizeFileComparator.SIZE_COMPARATOR.sort(filteredFiles);
```

However while the Name\Extension\SizeFileComparator use works, the sort is marked in red in Intellij giving me a message of: `Cannot resolve method sort(java.io.File[])`. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must instantiate the class NameFileComparator.

```
NameFileComparator comparator = new NameFileComparator();
comparator.sort(...)
```